# Is it always bad practice to start an ID with a number? (CSS)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

In my project I have submissions and comments, each with an ID. Currently the ID's are just numeric and correspond to their database ID's. Everything is working fine but when I run it through the W3 validator I get the error:

`value of attribute "id" invalid: "1" cannot start a name`

I suppose instead that I could just precede all ids with some sort of string but then whenever I was using or manipulating the id in JQuery or PHP I have to do a id.replace('string', '') before using it. This seems rather cumbersome. Any advice?

Comment: If it's invalid in the flavor of HTML you're using, it's worse than bad practice. It's just invalid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes, using numbers as HTML element IDs is bad practice.

1. **It violates W3C specification.**
   You noted this in your question, and it is true for every HTML specification except HTML5
2. **It is detrimental to SEO.**
   Search-engine optimized HTML element IDs SHOULD  reflect the content of the identified element.  Check out *[How To Compose HTML ID and Class Names like a Rockstar](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/how-to-compose-html-id-and-class-names-like-a-rockstar/)* by Meitar Moscovitz.  It provides a good overview of this concept.
3. **There can be server-side scripting issues.**
   Back when I first started programming in ASP classic, I had to access submitted form fields by a syntax like `Request.Form("some_id")`.  However, if I did `Request.Form(1)` it would return the value of the second field in the form collection, instead of the element with an Id equal to 1.  This is a pretty standard behavior for working with collections.  Its also similar with javascript, and could make your client side scripting more complicated to maintain as well.

Comment: In your form example, wouldn't you just be able to access it by Request.Form("1")?  - Not the point here, obviously :)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to use prefixes "comment-ID" or "post-ID".

If you need the id in JavaScript, you just have to `id.substring(8)` (for "comment-")

Comment: Obviously add the prefix in your HTML **only**.

Comment: @fazo: These are not variable names.

Comment: @fazo: Can you clarify on that point? I am also curious as to CSS naming conventions. Should I use camelCase, words separated by underscores, dashes, or just everything lowercase?

Comment: @LekisS: I have used `element.id.split("-").pop()` instead of `substring` in the past -- bit longer, but works without needing to hardcode the 8.

Comment: @Jon: oh you can use what you prefer. I think substring() is faster, but I'm not sure ;)

Comment: @LekisS: It's not about what I prefer, or what is faster (are you going to notice the extra 1msec?). It would be "better code" IMHO.

Comment: I like to use replace. It is very clear about what it is doing (getting rid of the prefix) and the first argument of the function indicates what you are manipulating. For example, id.replace('submission, '').

Answer (score 4):

The HTML 5 Specification lifts this restriction. If you're worried about validity you might simply consider changing the DTD to HTML5's.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 2):

If you're manipulating the element then you can just use `$(this).jQueryOperation()` - therefore you can have a prefix without having to replace anything!

Answer (score 0):

The best way for your need is having the prefix for your class, I mean something like **item-`x`** and `x` is the number that you need.

But from my personal experience, it is better to use classes for your elements, and you know that you must use classes if the item is not unique in the page